# Multi users bug with events Jquery Week Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, jquery-week-calendar

I'm using Jquery Week Calendar plugin, and almost everything is working fine, but this: When I give my array of user names to the "users" option, it loads all users from my array BUT do not show ANY events. And obviously when I disable the "users" options, all event are loaded.

It seems that my user names array is having conflict with events.

***What might be happening ??***

Let's take a look at the code:

**Creating events:**

```
var eventData1 = {
    options: {
    timeslotsPerHour: 4,
    timeslotHeight: 20,
    showAsSeparateUsers: true
  },
  events : [
     {'id':1, 'start': new Date(year22, month22, day22, 12), 'end': new Date(year22, month22, day22, 13, 30),'title':'Lunch with Mike'},
     {'id':2, 'start': new Date(year22, month22, day22, 14), 'end': new Date(year22, month22, day22, 14, 45),'title':'Dev Meeting'},
     {'id':3, 'start': new Date(year22, month22, day22 + 1, 18), 'end': new Date(year22, month22, day22 + 1, 18, 45),'title':'Hair cut'},
     {'id':4, 'start': new Date(year22, month22, day22 - 1, 8), 'end': new Date(year22, month22, day22 - 1, 9, 30),'title':'Team breakfast'},
     {'id':5, 'start': new Date(year22, month22, day22 + 1, 14), 'end': new Date(year22, month22, day22 + 1, 15),'title':'Product showcase'}
  ]
};
```

**Loading events in calendar:**

```
    data: function(start, end, callback) {
      console.log(eventData1);
      callback(eventData1);
    }
```

**Other options:**

```
users: usersWs, // user names array
showAsSeparateUsers: true,
displayOddEven: true,
displayFreeBusys: false,
displayEvents: true,
allowCalEventOverlap: true,
businessHours : {start: 7, end: 23, limitDisplay: true},
firstDayOfWeek : 1,
daysToShow: 6,
```

I'm available for more details.
Thank you all for the attention.

Comment: i just tried it. In the official documentation, when it create an event, it passes only id, start, end and title parameters. https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

Comment: you can see here that they pass also the userId [jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar_demo_3.html](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/2e4fae3cc97962cb3b618082fc7e3e00dc99bc53/weekcalendar_demo_3.html)

Comment: WOW!! I just miss that example, i will try it and give a return here, just a sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `events` to `users` by adding `userId: [id]` to every event, example :

```
events : [
     {'id':1, 'start': ..., 'end': ...,'title':'Lunch with Mike', userId: [id]},
     {'id':2, 'start': ..., 'end': ...,'title':'Dev Meeting', userId: , userId: [id]},
     ...
]
```

That should work take a look at **[official demo for multi-user](https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar/blob/2e4fae3cc97962cb3b618082fc7e3e00dc99bc53/weekcalendar_demo_3.html)**.